# Regex - find all hosts inside a url

Tags: regex

Given the following url:

```
http://clk.atdmt.com/FLO/go/364329512/direct/01/?href=http://www.****123****.com/refer.do?r=linkshare&lsid=vl0mfKZlvKU-I%2AKKCkbqWO7Zb9aqRSVLEw&lsurl=http%3A%2F%2F****123****%2Fcollection.do%3Fdataset%3D12905%26cm_mmc%3DIM_AFFILIATES-_-Linkshare-vl0mfKZlvKU-_-10003079-_-3
```

Is there any expression that will match all the hosts above? (e.g http://clk.atdmt.com, http://****123****.com....)

I need the same expression to work even in the matched string will be http://clk.atdmt.com

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are working with a text editor, use URL parser in your language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (javascript flavour) to extract the host (capture group 1):

```
/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)/g
```